# ¿Cómo hacer que al presionar un botón, el programa vuelva a iniciar?

Tags: java, eclipse, bucles, dialog

En mi escuela me piden que en el siguiente programa, al finalizar, cuando salga una cuadro de dialogo que diga "¿Volver a intentar? Si No", al presionar "Sí" reinicie el programa para volver a contestar la pregunta y al presionar "No" salga del programa

package Porgrama18.copy;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PreguntasCapitales {

```
String nombre; 
int respuesta;
int cierre;

ImageIcon PresentacionGato = new ImageIcon ("C:/Users/angel/Desktop/programacion/Imagenes estados/Presentación.gif");
ImageIcon ImagenBajaCalifornia = new ImageIcon ("C:/Users/angel/Desktop/programacion/Imagenes estados/Baja California.jpg");

public void Presentacion() {
    nombre = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,("Examen de los estados. \nTranquilo, es facil \nEscribe tu nombre antes de empezar"),("Examen"),JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, PresentacionGato, null, null);
}

public void BajaCalifornia() {

    respuesta = Integer.parseInt((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,("¿Cuál es la capital de Baja california? \n1] Tijuana \n2] Mexicali \n3] Ensenada"),("Pregunta 1"),JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagenBajaCalifornia, null, null));
    
}   

public void Espera() {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,("Hola, "+nombre+".\nEstás a punto de recibir tu puntuación.\nEspero no estés nervioso."),("Espera uwu"),JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
    public void cierre() {
        cierre = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Quieres volver a intentarlo?");

    }
```

}

Comment: Tienes que hacer que el metodo principal que se encargue de hacer que el juego funcione tenga un bucle, este bucle tiene que tener un flujo controlado, para que tu PC no explote, y lo unico que tendrias que hacer es manejar tu programa con `switch y cases`, es una de las cosas que se hace en `python`, aunque bueno... ahora que lo pienso al tratarse de java quiza no sea del todo necesario el bucle...

Comment: No sabemos que hace exactamente tu programa, pero de primeras parece ser una trivia usando `JOPtions` y etc, así que es mas sencillo, simplemente en el metodo de cierre, en el momento en que haces la pregunta deberias ejecutar dentro de si mismo la funcion que hace las preguntas si el usuario confirma, en caso contrario cierras el programa o haces lo que desees, nada mas es cuestion de usar un `if-else`, ahora bien, yo ya te di las pautas y posibles cosas que puedes hacer, espero edites la pregunta y nos muestres si lograste implementarlo o que errores te dio.

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido al sitio!, te felicito por crear una pregunta valida y bien formulada, normalmente los nuevos integrantes no realizan preguntas tan bien hechas. Igual por ser nuevo te invito a que pases por el [tour], y si bien haz preguntado bien, estas son las normativas de la comunidad por si tienes curiosidad: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, debes hacer que el recuadro sea ciclíco con un bucle **while ó do-while**

Seguido tendrás que definir el JOptionPane con los recuadros SÍ/NO (*YES_NO_OPTION*) para así leer y darle instrucciones al bucle.

Para finalizar en tu método *cierre()* deberás definir que sucederá si seleccionas SÍ o NO.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente es hacer un ciclo do-while, el ciclo do-while se ejcuta una vez, después evalúa la condición, debes saber que de presionar "Si", "No" o "Cancelar" recibirás los enteros 0 para "Si", 1 para "No" y 2 para "Cancelar", por lo que deberás decir que tu programa se repita siempre y cuando el valor de tu variable sea 0. Una forma de hacerlo es en tu método main y no en tu método cierre, tus métodos se ejecutarán una vez, luego, si la condición de que tu variable **cierre** sea = 0 se cumple, se vuelven a ejecutar.

Algo como:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cierre;
    PreguntasCapitales obj = new PreguntasCapitales();
    do {
      obj.Presentacion();
      obj.BajaCalifornia();
      obj.Espera();
      cierre = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Quieres volver a intentarlo?");
    }while(cierre == 0);
}
```